# How to get successive random subsamples?

Tags: python, random

I'm aiming to randomly take a sample of items from a list and then take a sample from that new list until only one item is left in the list.

**Code:**

```
from random import sample

exampleList = ["Gary","Kerry","Larry","Bob","Frank","Joshua"]

def reduce(List):
    newList = sample(List, random.randint(1, len(List)))
    return newList

reduce(reduce(reduce(reduce(exampleList)))) #<-- I want to avoid doing this#
```

Comment: Why not just take one item from the list? What are you trying to do? What's the desired output? Which version of python are you using? Also please include your `import` statements- what's `sample()`?

Comment: I want something like:
["Gary","Kerry","Larry","Bob","Frank","Joshua"]
["Gary","Kerry","Larry","Bob"]
["Gary","Kerry"]
["Gary"]

Comment: Do you want to extract an item at a time?

Comment: BTW, don't name your function `reduce`, there's already a standard function with that name.

Comment: Randomly shuffle the list. Then take a series of sublists: `l[1:]`, `l[2:]`, `l[3:]`, etc.

Comment: @Barmar you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
from random import sample, seed

seed(0)  # set the seed

chosen = [exampleList[:]]  # start with a copy of the original list

for n in range(len(exampleList)-1, 0, -1):
    chosen.append(sample(chosen[-1], n))  # successively append samples
print(chosen)
#[['Gary', 'Kerry', 'Larry', 'Bob', 'Frank', 'Joshua'],
# ['Bob', 'Joshua', 'Gary', 'Kerry', 'Larry'],
# ['Kerry', 'Gary', 'Joshua', 'Larry'],
# ['Gary', 'Joshua', 'Kerry'],
# ['Joshua', 'Gary'],
# ['Joshua']]
```

You initialize the output list to contain a copy of the original list. Then loop over values of `n` from `len(exampleList) - 1` through `1` and take a sample of that size from the last element of the output list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
ret = []
while len(exampleList) > 1:
    ret.append(exampleList)
    exampleList = reduce(exampleList)
ret.append(exampleList)
```